# Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to load from my database using ajax and it work.

here is my source code:

```
   $.ajax({  
    type: "GET",
    url: "a/aa.php",             
    dataType: "json",            
    success: function(response){                    
        var trHTML = '';
    $.each(response, function (i, item) {
        trHTML += '<tr role="row" ><td class="" >' + item.id + '</td><td class="copyte">'+ item.zuser + '</td><td class="copyte"> ' + item.user + '</td><td>' + item.zcode + '</td><td>' + item.zcountry + '</td><td>' + item.zsc + '</td><td>' + item.zip + '</td><td  data-id="' + item.zid + '" class=" deltype"><i class="fa fa-trash-alt"></i></td></tr>';
    });
    $('#myTable').append(trHTML);
    
    }
});
```

I am trying to make the content in "td" copyable by clicking on it. I made this attempt and it works fine but it is not working on the table created from the connection and it gives this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined
```

the code

```
 $('.copyte').click(function(e) {
        var $temp = $("<input>");
        $("body").append($temp);
        $temp.val($(this).html()).select();
        document.execCommand("copy");
        $temp.remove();
        Command: toastr["success"]($(this).html() + " copied", "DONE");
    });
```

Comment: And what line does the error refer to?

Comment: [here](https://i.ibb.co/QddnKtJ/image.png) @EmielZuurbier

Comment: Could you reproduce the issue by making a version that we can run, request and all. It's too hard to tell. It's almost as if the `this` keyword does not refer to an element, but to something else. Could you check the `this` value wherever it occurs in your function?